# logarithm trigonometry polynomial inequality

Tags: inequality

Solve for x: $$(x^2-4x+3) \log_{1/\sqrt2} (\cos^2 \pi x +\cos x + 2\sin x) \geqslant 2$$
How do i approach this? There are polynomial, log and trigonometry all in one. $(x^2-4x+3)\geqslant 0$ or $<0$ gives a certain range of $x$. How do I open the log part? Then what about the trig par? The answer is given as $x=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by simplifying:                                                                                          $$log_{1/√2}(cos^2πx+cosx+2sinx)$$
$$log_{1/√2}A = log_{{2}^{-1/2}}A = -2log_2A
$$
Therefore:
$$ -2(x^2 -4x +3)log_2(cos^2πx+cosx+2sinx) \ge 2$$
$$ -1(x^2 -4x +3)log_2(cos^2πx+cosx+2sinx) \ge 1$$
$$ log_2(cos^2πx+cosx+2sinx)^{-(x^2 -4x +3)} \ge 1$$
$$ log_2(1/(cos^2πx+cosx+2sinx))^{(x^2 -4x +3)} \ge 1$$

taking anti logarithm on both sides
$$\frac{1}{(cos^2πx+cosx+2sinx)^{(x^2 -4x +3)}} \ge 2$$
There are two cases for the above equation

case1: $(cos^2πx+cosx+2sinx) \ge 2$  and $(x^2 -4x +3) \le -1$
this case gives answer x = 2
[image: equations for case 1]
[image: case 1]

case2: $(cos^2πx+cosx+2sinx) \le \frac{1}{2}$  and $(x^2 -4x +3) \ge 1 [image: equations for case 2]

[image: case 2]

$(x^2 -4x +3) \ge 1$ equation gives range of $ x \le 2 - √2$ and $ x \ge 2 + √2$

this case gives the range of values for x

Comment: @ prakhar joshi thank you so much for your reply.but i have a few queries.

Comment: for case:1 $(x^2 -4x +3) \le -1 \rightarrow (x-2)^2 \le 0 \rightarrow x \le 2$how do i show that the values of x other than 2 are not relevant for case1.For case 2  how can $(cos^2πx) \ge 1$ ever be possible isn't it supposed to be$0 \le (cos^2πx) \le 1$ always!

Comment: infact $y=x^2 -4x +3$ is an upward opening parabola with vertex@(2,-1) so its value can't be $< -1$ so the inequality holds at y=-1 i.e at x=2.now the question is what/how does the trigo part contribute in any way to this?